# Java to JIRA data fetching

Tags: java, jira

How can I fetch data from JIRA using Java?
What are the steps and ideas?
The program should automatically connect Jira and fetch data
Please help

Comment: You should use the JIRA REST API, as documented here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/

Comment: The question is too broad. JIRA has REST APIs so start from there.

Comment: Yes. I'm new to the programming world. I'll check into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to access Jira and you need to differentiate between Jira Cloud and Jira Server (since you didn't specify which one you want to access).

**Jira Cloud**

Jira Cloud only offers a REST API to communicate. Have a look at the [REST API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/) (Supported authentication: Basic Auth, JWT, OAuth) or the [get started guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform) to create your own app for Jira Cloud.

**Jira Server**

Jira Server offers a [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/) (Supported authentication: Basic Auth) as well as a [Java API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/java-apis/) to access data. There are also [guides to get you started](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/) using the Java API by creating your own Jira app for Jira Server.

Comment: I got URI and fetched data from JIRA through postman, How can I achieve the same through java program? Please provide the necessary maven dependency

Comment: As linked in my response, there is a page explaining important parts to include Jira's Java API, see here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/java-apis/ There is also a page about "working with Maven" if you develop apps for Atlassian software like Jira, see here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/tutorials-and-guides/